# How to stop Windows explorer showing columns 'Date Taken' and 'Rating' etc on folders containing an image

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

I'm using Windows Vista at work (Business edition). Normally if I open Explorer in details view I see the columns Name, Date modified, Type and Size. Sometimes i'll open a folder that contains an image and the columns will instead be Name, Date taken, Tags, Size and Rating.

I find this really annoying. Can I stop Windows doing this?

Comment: This is a well known bug in Windows Vista and there are no solution other than upgrading to Windows Seven. The solution by Gani work sometimes but eventually Windows will forget the setting and display random or no columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After customizing a single folder to your liking simply do this: 
**Windows Explorer** => **Organize** => **Folder and search options** (alternatively **Tools** => **Folder options**) => **View** Tab => Under the **Folder views** click "**Apply to Folder**" button.

Assuming you do that for pictures, it will use this customization for all other folders that uses folder type of pictures. You can do the same for document, video, music folders as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply this to all folders by selecting all the folders in the C:\ directory and doing the Properties->Customise->"What type of folder do you want" thing. If you select "also apply this template to all subfolders", all your folders will be in that style! I have just set all of mine to "document" style. If you create a new folder in the C:\ directory, you'll have to do it again for the new folder.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click on the column name bar.
2. On the dropdown menu, uncheck the
   Date Taken item.

Comment: Thanks -- but I would have to do that for every single folder this happens with and not just remove the columns I don't want but add the columns I do from a giant list of available columns. Is there an easier way? BTB

Comment: @BTB, the Date Taken column will only appear in folders set as of the Pictures and Videos type (which contain only pictures and videos). Make sure that you store documents in folders of the Documents type. To change the type of a folder right-click on it; on the dropdown menu, click Properties; on the Properties dialog, click the Customize tab; in the "What type of folder do you want?" groupbox, select Documents from the combobox.